# libJdbcOdbc SQLAllocEnv undefined and dynamic linking in general

Tags: java, jdbc, shared-libraries, elf

I am receiving the message when running an application

```
java: symbol lookup error: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so: undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv
```

the purpose of the application is to migrate data from one server to another using the Pentaho kettle jar files.  I am using a Jdbc-Odbc connection on the destination server.  I recently installed java (jre and jdk) from Oracles web site.  When I set

```
export LD_DEBUG=all
```

I see the following response

```
binding file /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__cxa_finalize' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
      5193:
      5193:     calling init: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so
      5193:
      5193:     opening file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so [0]; direct_opencount=1
      5193:
      5193:     symbol=JNI_OnLoad;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=JNI_OnLoad;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so [0]
      5193:     binding file /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so [0] to /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so [0]: normal symbol `JNI_OnLoad'
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libm.so.6 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
      5193:     /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv (fatal)
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libm.so.6 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so [0]
      5193:     /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv (fatal)
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libm.so.6 [0]
      5193:     /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv (fatal)
      5193:     symbol=Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so [0]
      5193:     binding file /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so [0] to /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so [0]: normal symbol `Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocEnv'
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=java [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/../jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libm.so.6 [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libm.so.6 [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0]
      5193:     symbol=SQLAllocEnv;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
      5193:     /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv (fatal)
```

I have unixODBC installed an clearly the implementation of these functions reside in libodbc.so(symbolic link to libodbc.so.2.0.0),

```
nm -a /usr/local/lib/libodbc.so | grep "SQLAllocEnv"
0000000000006f30 T SQLAllocEnv
0000000000000000 a SQLAllocEnv.c
```

I have /usr/local/lib in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH ( I did export ). I also placed a new configuration file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d and ran ldconfig.  But for some reason this function ( and presumably others) will not load.

Also

```
ldd /usr/java/latest/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff09728000)
        libjava.so => /usr/java/latest/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so (0x00007fb8d03ab000)
        libjvm.so => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb8d000d000)
        libjvm.so => not found
        libverify.so => /usr/java/latest/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so (0x00007fb8cfdfe000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb8cfbfa000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000368b000000)
        libjvm.so => not found
```

Can anyone give me any suggestions to how I can fix this.  It is to my understanding that when the linker is resolving calls dynamically it will use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to search for elf files. Is this correct?  Is there some kind of index that gets built to find shared libraries with the needed functions?  I am aware of the ld.so.cache that gets created, but there must be some index i.e.
SQLAllocEnv -> x.so, libodbc.so, etc . What makes the linker look up symobols in those particular files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error simply means that few libraries files are not found in the default location. You can export this like export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/java/latest/jre/lib/amd64 in your case. And it should resolve the problem.